# How to show an annotation in offline map [tpk]

Tags: cordova, annotations, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

How to display an annotation in offline tpk in ARCGIS for javascript?

what i have is the lat long information and just want to display an annotation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you need to accomplish two tasks in a JavaScript Web application:

1. Display a tile package (.tpk)
2. Display an annotation

For displaying a tile package, try the [offline-editor-js library](https://github.com/Esri/offline-editor-js). One of the samples displays a TPK.

For displaying an annotation, use the [`Graphic` class](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphic-amd.html) in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript. You can use [`TextSymbol`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/textsymbol-amd.html) to display your lon/lat text or [`SimpleMarkerSymbol`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/simplemarkersymbol-amd.html) to display a marker. There are [several samples](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/#graphics) showing how to use graphics.